# The number of AR sequences with indecomposable middle term in $D_n/I$ cases

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

In the following $A_n/I$ or $D_n/I$ cases means the AR quiver of bound quiver algebra $A_n/I$ or $D_n/I$.

I know that the number of AR sequences with indecomposable middle term in $A_n/I$ cases is always $n-1$ using the results about string algebras. Here the orientations and ideal $I$ are both arbitrary.

Now I am considering the $D_n/I$ cases. For $D_4/I$, the number can be 3 or 6, for $D_5/I$, the number can be 4 or 7 or 9.

I also find that if there is no AR sequences with middle term having three indecomposable middle terms in the AR quiver of a $D_n/I$ quiver, then the number is always 
$n-1$, which is the same as $A_n/I$. This also needs to be proved.

Is there a general characterization of the number for $D_n/I$ cases? $A_n/I$ are special cases of string algebras, then $D_n/I$ are special cases of what kind of algebras?

Any suggestions are warmly welcome!

Comment: You didn't specify what $A_n/I$ or $D_n/I$ is. ould you please do so.

Comment: I have added the explantion at the beginning of the question. @Julian Kuelshammer